# Allow resize to ignore max-height?

Tags: html, css

I have some code like the first snippet - I am curious if there is a way to use resize and allow it to ignore max-height?

The reason I don't just use height is I want the div to fit the first piece of content without white space. I included that at the end if you want to check it out.

Basically I am trying to get something that looks like the first one, but functions like the second one.

Thanks!

```css
.content {
  max-height: 5em;
 overflow-y: auto;
 resize: vertical;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">One line</div>
<div class="content">Multi
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
line</div>
```

This doesn't work for what I'm trying to do due to the excess whitespace:

```css
.content {
  height: 5em;
 overflow-y: auto;
 resize: vertical;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">One line</div>
<div class="content">Multi
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
line</div>
```

In response to the first answer, the content is dynamic. I have provided a dynamic example

```js
rand1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
rand2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "Start"
for (var i = 0; i < rand1; i++) {
  document.getElementById("1").innerHTML += ".\n"
}
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "Start"
for (var i = 0; i < rand2; i++) {
  document.getElementById("2").innerHTML += ".\n"
}
```

```css
.content {
  max-height: 5em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  resize: vertical;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="1"></div>
<div class="content" id="2"></div>
```

Answer (score 22):

You can do it with pure css. When you resize an element, a height property is automatically generated within the style tag of the html element.

If you make a css selector that references that attribute and cancels the max-height in case "height" exists, you get the effect you want.

```css
.content {
  max-height: 5em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  resize: vertical;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
 }
.content[style*="height"] {
  max-height: unset; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple & elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first division class as below <strike>`<div class="content">One line</div>`</strike>.

`<div>One line</div>`

Comment: The content of the div in my actual project is dynamically generated, meaning that it may or may not need the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear. Seems that you want a dynamically heigh first container and a maxed height second one, is it?

If you want something that is filling up the first `div` as much as content in it, you can use a `min-height` for the first container and just use `max-height` just for the second one.